# Using dilated convolution in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

In [WaveNet](https://deepmind.com/blog/article/wavenet-generative-model-raw-audio), dilated convolution is used to increase receptive field of the layers above.

[image: Dilated convolution]

From the illustration, you can see that layers of dilated convolution with kernel size 2 and dilation rate of powers of 2 create a tree like structure of receptive fields. I tried to (very simply) replicate the above in Keras.

```
import tensorflow.keras as keras
nn = input_layer = keras.layers.Input(shape=(200, 2))
nn = keras.layers.Conv1D(5, 5, padding='causal', dilation_rate=2)(nn)
nn = keras.layers.Conv1D(5, 5, padding='causal', dilation_rate=4)(nn)
nn = keras.layers.Dense(1)(nn)
model = keras.Model(input_layer, nn)
opt = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001)
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=opt)
model.summary()
```

And the output:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
input_4 (InputLayer)         [(None, 200, 2)]          0
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_5 (Conv1D)            (None, 200, 5)            55
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_6 (Conv1D)            (None, 200, 5)            130
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 200, 1)            6
=================================================================
Total params: 191
Trainable params: 191
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

I was expecting `axis=1` to shrink after each `conv1d` layer, similar to the gif. Why is this not the case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The model summary is as expected. As you note using dilated convolutions results in an increase in the receptive field. However, *dilated convolution actually preserves the output shape of our input image/activation as we are just changing the convolutional kernel.* A regular kernel could be the following

```
0 1 0
1 1 1
0 1 0
```

A kernel with a dilation rate of 2 would add zeros in between each entry in our original kernel as below.

```
0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
1 0 1 0 1
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 0
```

In fact you can see that our original kernel is also a dilated kernel with a dilation rate of 1. Alternative ways to increase the receptive field result in a downsizing of the input image. Max pooling and strided convolution are 2 alternative methods.

For example. if you want to increase the receptive field by decreasing the size of your output shape you could use strided convolution as below. I replace the dilated convolution with a strided convolution. You will see that the output shape reduces every layer.

```
import tensorflow.keras as keras
nn = input_layer = keras.layers.Input(shape=(200, 2))
nn = keras.layers.Conv1D(5, 5, padding='causal', strides=2)(nn)
nn = keras.layers.Conv1D(5, 5, padding='causal', strides=4)(nn)
nn = keras.layers.Dense(1)(nn)
model = keras.Model(input_layer, nn)
opt = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001)
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=opt)
model.summary()

Model: "model_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
input_2 (InputLayer)         [(None, 200, 2)]          0
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_3 (Conv1D)            (None, 100, 5)            55
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_4 (Conv1D)            (None, 25, 5)             130
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 25, 1)             6
=================================================================
Total params: 191
Trainable params: 191
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

To summarize dilated convolution is just another way to increase the receptive field of your model. It has the benefit of preserving the output shape of your input image.

Comment: It should probably be added that dilated convolution is usually used with stride. Dilated convolutions change the receptive field of a kernel, whereas stride changes the output shape so the next layer has a bigger receptive field. Dilation alone doesn't change the receptive field a whole lot when used across multiple layers without stride. But unfortunately Keras doesn't support dilated conv with stride.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of this dialtion with 1D Convolutional layers, output has size 14:

https://github.com/jwallbridge/translob/blob/master/python/LobFeatures.py

```
def lob_dilated(x):
  """
  TransLOB dilated 1-D convolution module
  """
  x = layers.Conv1D(14,kernel_size=2,strides=1,activation='relu',padding='causal')(x)   
  x = layers.Conv1D(14,kernel_size=2,dilation_rate=2,activation='relu',padding='causal')(x)
  x = layers.Conv1D(14,kernel_size=2,dilation_rate=4,activation='relu',padding='causal')(x)
  x = layers.Conv1D(14,kernel_size=2,dilation_rate=8,activation='relu',padding='causal')(x)
  y = layers.Conv1D(14,kernel_size=2,dilation_rate=16,activation='relu',padding='causal')(x)

  return y
```